# Create property in MSBuild with result of a boolean expression

Tags: msbuild, maintainability

Is there a neat way to create "boolean" properties to use in MSBuild? I can evaluate the expression inside a `Condition` attribute, but not inside the Value attribute of a `CreateProperty` task.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
<CreateProperty Value="'$(IncludeInBuild)'=='' OR 
    '$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::IsMatch($(MSBuildProjectFullPath), 
    $(IncludeInBuild)'=='True'">
    <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="MatchesInclude" />
</CreateProperty>
```

What that gives me is not True or False, but

```
''=='' OR '$([System.Text...
```

Can I evaluate a boolean expression and set a property with the result? My workaround now is just to repeat the expression in Condition attributes wherever I need it.

Comment: There's something wrong with the parentheses in the boolean expression you give for an example, so it's unclear where the `RegEx` *pattern* string is coming from and/or what input string you're trying to match against the `$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)` to generate a boolean value. Maybe these unrelated problems are why you (incorrectly?) thought you needed to use the MSBuild `CreateProperty` task at all in the first place?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

How about creating a default property 'false' with a condition to assign true if the condition passes?

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <MatchesInclude>false</MatchesInclude>
    <MatchesInclude Condition="'$(IncludeInBuild)'=='' OR 
    '$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::IsMatch($(MSBuildProjectFullPath), 
    $(IncludeInBuild)'=='True'">true</MatchesInclude>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: This is in fact what I ended up doing.

Comment: However, it is inelegant, as using the variables in conditionals must be of the form 
    '$(MatchesInclude)' == 'true'.  

We would like something like the Exists function which is evaluation to boolean directly so that one can use something like 
    Condition="$(MatchesInclude)" 
to enhance readability

Comment: @TomWest just convert it `$([System.Convert]::ToBoolean(false))` and `$([System.Convert]::ToBoolean(true))`